# Why this code returns Garbage value?

Tags: c, printf, conditional-statements

My Code:

```
void main()
{
     while(1){
         if(printf("%d",printf("%d")))
             break;
         else
             continue;
     }
}
```

I know that `printf()` returns the number of characters printed.So, why the above code outputs `Garbage values` when it should output 1.
Please explain.

Thanks.

Comment: The second parameter of your leftmost printf should be a number.  You have instead passed it a function printf.  That's like trying to put gummy bears in your gas tank so it will run.  Please read up on what printf is: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Comment: Are you familiar with the parameter conventions of `printf`? If so, a little bit of code inspection would solve your problem. And what is the purpose of having it in a `while` loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the second `printf` is missing the number that it is supposed to print...

BTW, don't expect to see just 1, you'll see the number printed by the second `printf` before that.  E.g. if your code is

```
printf("%d",printf("%d", 7));
```

you'll see 71; first 7 will be printed and then 1.

Comment: "you'll see the number printed by the second printf before that." What is that value ?

Comment: Would it not be 422? printf returns the number of characters written so printf("%d", 42) should return 2.

Comment: @NigelHarper, right, it was 1 in the question but I wanted to print 42 and did not stop to think. Fixed the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Because you didn't provide argument for inner `printf`'s `%d`

Check with :

`if(printf("%d",printf("%d ",3)))` , notice I used a space after `%d`

Now you'll see

`3 2`

last `2` because of an extra space

Comment: Thanks. But I still I don't get why my code gave garbage values?

Comment: @user2708039 read the first line of my post 
`%d` is a format specifier for `printf` which demands an integer, since you didn't provide one you'll get Undefined behaviour

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("%d",printf("%d"))
```

equal to

```
int i = printf("%d");
printf("%d",i);
```

However, the `int i =printf("%d");` line will printf a garbage value because you don't give it the value it need.